# Flutter: RTMP Stream showing watermark and text in video output realtime

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

I am trying to include a watermark and text details while video streaming,in Flutter using the video_stream/rtmp_broadcaster package, is this even possible?